# How to calculate data drift in text data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am training a binary classifier for text data. I'm having an accuracy score of 98.12% and f1 score of 95%. The problem is i trained my model using a 5 year old data-set. I am pretty sure that data drift will occur at some point and my model's performance will be affected. I am already monitoring the confidence score and if there's any sudden drop in a given window size, i will be alerted. Is there any way to identify the sudden data drift and alert me?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: all methods to detect drift are heuristic. One can use anyone or even many together, still they are heuristic in essense else machine learning would not exist and one would have perfect knowledge of everything

Comment: an interesting approach https://blog.dominodatalab.com/data-drift-detection-for-image-classifiers/

Comment: data drift detection approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-monitor-data-drift

Comment: For images i've tried auto-encoder to regenerate and calculate the loss but i'm not able to find a better solution for text data other than monitoring the confidence threshold. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of unstructured data is that its rarely changes over time. Cat looks like Cat for 100 years. Most English sentences will be same, for next 50 years, unless lots of business acronyms or sort forms appears over time.

**Solution:**
If it happens you can always create a base bag of word or any matrix to calculate the frequency or that represents the population in some statistical measure.
Write a function to keep comparing the above with new data in a sliding window. Window size varies case by case.